# childbrowser not working ios6 phonegap 2.0

Tags: xcode, ios6, phonegap-plugins

I see the following problems using ChildBrowser plugin in ios phonegap.
My mapping file is updated with ChildBrowserCommand and I allowed external hosts to *
My Environment
Xcode 4.5
ios 6
Phonegap 2.0

2012-09-26 12:36:07.419 HelloWorld2[2566:c07] ERROR: Plugin 'ChildBrowserCommand' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in Cordova.plist.
2012-09-26 12:36:07.420 HelloWorld2[2566:c07] FAILED pluginJSON = [null,"ChildBrowserCommand","
showWebPage",["http://google.com"]]

Answer (score 0):

They released recently v2.1, I suggest you giving it a try since now they are supposed to officially support ChildBrowser plugin

Comment: I already tried latest phonegap and plugins, this didn't work